# Extract strings from another string beginning and ending with a special char

Tags: php, regex, string, split, substring

let's say I have a string like

> This {is} a new {test} {string} from me.

My intention is to get all the strings surrounded by the `{` and `}` in a array, or a list.
So I want to get:

> {is} {test} {string}

Substring won't work here. Probably 'regex' is the solution, but I just can't get it to work for me. Can someone help?

Comment: _what_ did you try then?

Comment: Show us your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a regular expression. In this case, you want to use the following regular expression:

```
/\{[^}]*\}/
```

What does this mean?

- `/` = start of regex
- `\{` = match the character `{`
- `[^}]` = match any character except `}`...
- `*` = ... 1 to unlimited times
- `\}` = match the character `}`
- `/` = end of regex

---

You can use this like so:

```
$re = "/\{[^}]*}/";
$str = "This {is} a new {test} {string} from me."; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

print_r($matches[0]);
```

where `$matches[0]` is an array of matches. This will output:

> Array ( [0] => {is} [1] => {test} [2] => {string} )

Comment: You saved my life, thank you very much!